# SQL Server 2005 workgroup edition users?

Tags: sql-server-2005

How many concurrent users on a Sql Server 2005 workgroup edition?

1 database?

Entire server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no built-in limitations - from [SQL Server 2005 Workgroup Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/workgroup.aspx):

> Workgroup Edition is the data
>   management solution for small
>   organizations that need a database
>   with **no limits on size or number of
>   users**. Workgroup Edition can serve as
>   a front-end Web server or for
>   departmental or branch office
>   operations. It includes the core
>   database features of the SQL Server
>   product line and is easy to upgrade to
>   Standard or Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0):

There are no limitations on the number of users. The limitations primarily are:

1. Doesn't run in 64bit mode (Uses Windows On Windows if
   installed on a 64bit OS) - therefore it has a 3GB ram limit
2. Limited to 2 CPUs

That being said, I also found the lack of Integration Services running on the engine (you could do it as a file that runs with the Windows scheduler) somewhat of a pain.